# jQuery TinyScrollbar won't show in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinyscrollbar

I am using jQuery TinyScrollbar plugin to add scrollbars to some content , on Firefox, it works but when I refresh, sometimes it disappears, on chrome, it doesn't show at all, I have follow the example on the website http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/ , and I don't know what's the problem.
The site where you can see the problem is at http://www.outstock.es/avances/index.php/products/show/1

Comment: When you look at the resources table of the chrome developer tools. Expand the files that contain the css, js and images for your TinyScrollbar. Do you see any files missing? Missing files are marked with a red exclamation point.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code on your page it looks like these two lines are hit too early:

```
$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar({ size: 600 });//lanzamos el scrollbar para la galeria
$('#scrollbar2').tinyscrollbar({ size: 600 });//lanzamos el scrollbar para la galeria simple
```

Make sure these are being hit in the DOM ready event in your general.js file

When i open your page and run those lines of code from the console your #scrollbar 1 appears.

**#Scrollbar2 does not exist exist on the page.**

You can confirm this by running this selector from the command line of the chrome dev tools:

```
$('#scrollbar2').length;
```

This returns 0 meaning the selector did not find a match.

Good Luck